# Индексация json файла и преобразование его в объект | TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть json:

```
{
    "ru": {
        "text_1": "Text #1",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Как мне с помошью TypeScript преобразовать его в объект? Просто нужна возможность получить любой текст по ключу: **langJSON.ru.text_1** или **langJSON['ru']['text_1']**. Импорт делается как обычный json: `import langJSON from './langJSON.json';`

**Самое важное,** что редактор должен определять возможные варианты, как на скрине, поэтому просто поставить `as any` не вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно создать интерфейс в typescript согласно структуре этого JSON файла и распарсить JSON в переменную с типом описанного интерфейса.

Comment: А вообще странно, что ваш редактор кода не подсказывает возможные значения для `langJSON`. В VS code ваш вариант импорта правильно распознается редактором.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, если использовать напрямую, то выдает через раз, но, если мне нужно, чтобы один из параметров функции был строкой из JSON, то нужно как-то индексировать файл, но не получается.

Comment: Про интерфейс я итак понимаю, но если строк у меня будет 1к+, то я охренею от того, сколько нужно сделать работы. + я не один работаю в проекте, поэтому по мере обновления JSON нужно и интерфейс обновлять будет. Думаю, TS должен иметь такие возможности, но я пока хз как.

Comment: typescript не умеет угадывать, какой объект ожидается. Он должен быть строго типизирован. Да typescript это не про скорость, а про качество. Мне кажется, ваш JSON это что то вроде справочника слов/выражений под разные языки. Если это так, то решается это дроблением типов

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, в чем особенность вашего редактора кода, но typescript умеет интерпретировать тип импортируемого JSON - файла. Чтобы индексировать ваш JSON, можно объявить тип через выражение `typeof` и затем индексировать тип по имени полей при помощи следующего синтаксиса: `TypeName['ru']['text_1']`. Пример ниже:

```
import langJSON from './langJSON.json';

type LangJSON = typeof langJSON;

// Индексация типа 'ru' объекта langJSON
function getText1Vaue(langSettings: LangJSON['ru']) {
  return langSettings.text_1;
}
```